# SF Symbols showing as "?"

Tags: macos, xcode

When trying to use SF Symbols in XCode version 11 I get a question mark symbol, however if I highlight the text the symbol shows and it shows correctly in the attribute inspector - Can anyone give any advice?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Your chosen font doesn't include the proper glyph, so it's showing the default placeholder. Xcode on the other hand used a different font for it's UI, so it shows up.

I'm not familiar with font rendering on MacOS, but on Windows, font rendering will automatically use a special font for missing symbols (if available), so it may be hard to tell from UI controls or word processors what's actually available.